# how to programatically adaptive screen in UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to find way how to programatically adaptive screen in the UWP app, but I can't get any related idea, is there anything like that?

Comment: What do you mean programmatically adaptive? You want to change the layout of the page in code?

Comment: I want to show like that page include with five button control then display full screen size, but when show only one button the screen size reduced, so how do i do.?

Comment: I have updated my answer with all possible approaches for this.

Comment: When i apply some condition, show only one button display after that screen size reduced, i'm beginner of UWP application developing, so really i did't understand you put the link. so may you send details about this application.

Comment: Just create a new UWP app project and copy and paste the first sample code into `MainPage.xaml` and launch it to see how it behaves. The `AdaptiveTrigger` for the `Wide` state is triggered when the app's window is wider than 600 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Triggers are the best solution for layout changes based on app's size. For examples see: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week03aug15/designing-with-adaptive-triggers-for-windows-10/ .

A simple example for two buttons:

```xml
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TestButton2.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="Test button" />
        <Button x:Name="TestButton2" Content="Test button" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Once the app is wider than 600 pixels, the second button will become visible.

## Other approaches

You can change the layout of the page in reaction to size changes using the `Page`'s `SizeChanged` event, which is fired each time the user resizes the page. This is not a clean approach however and you are much better suited using the built-in adaptive triggers for this.

```cs
//in the page's constructor wire-up the SizeChanged event
this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;       

private void MainPage_SizeChanged( object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e )
{
   if ( e.NewSize.Width < 768 )
   {
      //some layout changes
   }
   else if (e.NewSize.Width < 1024)
   {
      //some layout changes
   }
   else
   {
      //etc.
   }
}
```

You can also manually switch the current `VisualState` for the page from code.

First define some `VisualStates` in XAML:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CustomGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="ShowButtonState" />
            <VisualState x:Name="HideButtonState">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TestButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="Test button" />
</Grid>
```

And then switch the states in code:

```cs
if ( someCondition )
{
   VisualStateManager.GoToState( this, "HideButtonState", false );
}            
else
{
   VisualStateManager.GoToState( this, "ShowButtonState", false );
}
```